# customized pager for Git

Tags: git

I wrote a script to display `git diff`. It will

1. display the difference in `stdout` if the output fits in the terminal screen, or
2. display the difference in pager otherwise.

My script:

```sh
#!/bin/sh

if ! git diff "$@" > /dev/null; then
    # not in a Git repository
    exit 1
fi

if [ `git diff "$@" | wc --lines` -gt `tput lines` ]; then
    git diff "$@" --color=always | less
else
    git diff "$@" --color=always | cat
fi
```

The current limitations of the script:

1. If I need to do the same with `git show` or `git log`, I need to write another two similar scripts (which is not DRY).
2. Auto-completion does not work. I need to write my own one (taking too much time).

Now I wish to write a script that does the same but works as a pager so that I can set Git configuration `core.pager` as the script and solve the problem mentioned.

Note: I am using Zsh.

### update

I tried `less --no-init --quit-if-one-screen` (`less -FX`), and it does almost what I need, except that it will not clear the screen in the more-than-one-page case. So actually I need the `--no-init` option to be conditional: disable initialization and quit if it fits one screen; no special action otherwise. Maybe `less --no-init-if-one-screen --quit-if-one-screen`?

Comment: Not really relevant, but why are you piping through cat?

Comment: @SeanAllred Because currently my `core.pager` is set as `less`. If it is not set at all, then I guess indeed I do not need to pipe through `cat`.

Comment: I think what you need is the `-F` option of less.

Comment: You mean like `git -p diff ...`?

Comment: @muru The `-F`/`--quit-if-one-screen` does detect the size and quit as I required, but I hope that it can also display the content to `stdout` instead of a simple exit. `less -FX` (`--no-init --quit-if-one-screen`) will do everything except that I want it to clear the screen if it is more than one screen.

Comment: @vonbrand I am sorry, but I have no idea what `git -p diff ...` means. (I had never tried options between `git` and the action such as `diff`.) I tried your suggestion, but the `-p` option did not seems to have done anything.

Comment: @FranklinYu, `git [flags] command [options] [arguments]`; flag `-p` (or `--paginate`) paginates the output of the command. And sorry, `diff` does a `-p` by default. Try e.g. `git -p ls-files`.

Comment: @vonbrand, Thank you! I read the doc with the full name of the option. This option "pipes all output into _less_ (or if set, $PAGER) if standard output is a terminal", while I actually want the "piping to less" to be conditional: pipe only if the output would be more than one page. Therefore, I guess this is not what I meant.